# Physically realizable (quantum) system

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Given a system of arbitrary number of commuting observables, can one always exhibit a system that realizes it? For example, suppose we have 3 diagonal (and, therefore, commuting) matrices

$X= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \end{array} \right)$

$Y= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$

$Z= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$

Is there a quantum system that realizes it?

Answer (score 0):

The minimal quantum system that realises this system is encoded in the Abelian C*-algebra generated by $X$, $Y$, $Z$ and the identity. This is isomorphic to the C*-algebra of continuous functions in 3 variables over the joint spectrum of $(X,Y,Z)$. I leave it to you to give a more concrete description of this C*-algebra in the specific case of this *discrete* example.

Comment: Is it an algebra of continuous functions whose zeroes are (1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,2,1),(3,2,2)? Is there a theorem that asserts that for every C*-algebra there is a physical system that realizes it?

Comment: as an axiom, a physical system is described by a unital C*-algebra, whose self-adjoint part gives the set of observables, and (a subset of) the state space gives the set of physical states. So if you have a unital C*-algebra you can think that this is representing some sort of physical system, whatever that is and however exotic it turns out to be. Moreover if the C*-algebra is commutative then it describes a classical system.